# Undefined function in CC compiler (minix)

Tags: c, undefined, cc

I have a mysterious problem!
In the main.c I have the following:

```
#include "jogo.h"
int main(){
    int i;
    sef_startup();
    vg_init(0x105);
    batalha_naval();
    sleep(5);
    vg_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

In the jogo.h I have:

```
#ifndef __JOGO_H
#define __JOGO_H
void batalha_naval(void);
#endif
```

And in the main.c I have:

```
#include "core.h"
void batalha_naval(void) {
    vg_draw_line(0, 0, 1023, 0, 12);
}
```

But when doing a make the compiler gives a `undefined _batalha_naval();` in the main.c. If I define the function in the jogo.h an error doesn't appear, but if I do like this the error appears.

I am using CC compiler.

Comment: Show us the command you're using to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your jogo.h appears correct.
   You need it if you wish to use function "batalha_naval()" in multiple compilation units.
2. You should '#include "jogo.h"' in main.c, and in jogo.c.
3. You must include both main and jogo in your link command.

Answer (score 0):

How are you linking?  You need to do either:

```
$ cc -c main.c
$ cc -c jogo.c
$ cc main.o jogo.o
```

or

```
$ cc main.c jogo.c
```

Comment: Ah, i see, that might be the problem!!